# BigQuery SQL User Agent Detecting

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-agent

How is it possible to extract information about
Device Type
Browser,
OS and etc.
from the user agent string as :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-A307G Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 170.2.0.30.474 Android (29/10; 280dpi; 720x1423; samsung; SM-A307G; a30s; exynos7904; es_US; 267925733)
```

Thanks

Comment: provide example of what exactly output you expect off of input data in your question

Comment: What is the context of your question? What platform are you using? Give an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to extract information like
Device Type 
Browser,
OS and etc.
I have seen similar questions here with static scripts,
But my question is how to get such information dynamically when my data is updated

Answer (score 2):

You can use the approach outlined here - https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=2af15c50-e1cb-4ce1-b641-f7263e66ac8a#gsc.tab=0 - upload a JavaScript User-Agent Parsing library into Google Cloud Storage. Then reference it in a Google Cloud BigQuery User Defined Function.

Based on this you can then - 1. save the function definition in BigQuery itself and 2. use it to Parse updated data using a View, something like `SELECT [my-project.[my-dataset].[parse_user_agent]([user_agent_field]) FROM [my-project].[my-dataset].[my-table]`. After that you can read the parsed information from the View.

I've tested this approach and it works.

After uploading the woothee.js file to a bucket in Google Cloud Storage, I created the function in Google Cloud BigQuery

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `[my-project].[my-dataset].user_agent_parse`(ua STRING)
 RETURNS STRUCT<category STRING, name STRING, version STRING, os STRING, vendor STRING, os_version STRING>
 LANGUAGE js AS """  return {category:woothee.parse(ua).category
 ,name:woothee.parse(ua).name
 ,version:woothee.parse(ua).version
 ,os:woothee.parse(ua).os
 ,vendor:woothee.parse(ua).vendor
 ,os_version:woothee.parse(ua).os_version};
"""OPTIONS(library="gs://[my-bucket]/woothee.js");
```

The only concern is that depending on your volume it might cost you quite a lot to basically parse again all the User Agents whenever you read from the View. Therefore you might want to consider storing the Parsed data in a table on a scheduled basis.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog post on the topic which covers how to do this in detail: [How To Extract Information From User Agent Strings in BigQuery?](https://textquery.app/2022/07/15/extract-information-user-agent-strings-bigquery/)

**Short answer**: via BigQuery's [Javascript UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions).

**Long Answer**: BigQuery allows you to directly use Javascript to define functions. It's a perfect solution for parsing user agents as there are many awesome UA parsers available for JS.

You can upload your preferred JS library (for eg, [UAParser.js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js)) to Google Storage. Then, you can use the `gsutil` URL to create a UDF. For eg,

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION funcs.parse_useragent(ua STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<
  browser STRUCT<name STRING, version STRING, major STRING>,
  engine  STRUCT<name STRING, version STRING>,
  os      STRUCT<name STRING, version STRING>,
  device  STRUCT<vendor STRING, model STRING, type STRING>,
  arch    STRING
>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let a = UAParser(ua);
  a.arch = a.cpu.architecture;
  return a;
"""
OPTIONS (
  library="gs://BUCKET_URL/ua-parser.min.js"
);
```

**Note**: `funcs` here is a dataset I created to store all UDFs. It can be any dataset.

Now this UDF can be used against the column that contains User-Agent strings.

```sql
SELECT
  funcs.parse_useragent(useragent) as ua
FROM `requests.reqs`
LIMIT 1000;
```

[image: BigQuery Output]